# Too much padding with MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im doing a heatmap from a pandas dataframe with matplotlib. Everything looks good, only I have too much padding on the top of the heatmap and I don't know how to change it:
[image: heatmap with too much padding on the top]

The code I am currently using:

```
plt.figure(num=1,figsize=(10,10))
plt.pcolor(table, cmap='Reds', vmin=0, vmax=5, edgecolors="black")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(table.index), 1), table.index)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(table.columns), 1), table.columns, rotation=45)
plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Is that because of yticks are strings and matplotlib is trying to make space in case I want to rotate them?

Thanks! Regars!

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem ... you can put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib tries to find a nice round number for the axis limits (e.g. 45 instead of 41) to make the plot look nicer with automated ticks. Redefining the ticks doesn't change the limits. You can manually force them to match your data exactly:

```
plt.gca().set_ylim((0, len(table.index)))
plt.gca().set_xlim((0, len(table.columns)))
```